# How could I merge multiple original laptop batteries together in series?

Tags: laptop, battery

My laptop batteries keep dying with half of their life left.

Basically a I have 2 * 1 hours old laptop batteries and a new 3 hours one.

There are all the same battery, same model, is there a way I could rig them together by connecting the wires so I could have a 5 hours battery lifespan?

I don't mind if it makes the laptop bulkier and I'm willing to take out the bottom cover and cut it so it fits, I'm OK about duct tapping the whole thing, don't care what it looks like, I want battery lifespan!

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Do you already own a fire extinguisher?

Comment: No, but I have running water, so could put off the fire ;)

Comment: You'll need a bucket you can quickly shovel it into. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCac4nW6JKQ

Comment: You don't extinguish a burning LiIon battery on fire with water - you'd possibly fuel it. Use sand.

Comment: Just don't play with those cells without **advanced** knowledge of electricity and electronics and also chemistry understanding could help. It's no joke they extremely dangerous. When you understand why the Ohm's law isn't the "law of nature" but it is an linear approximation of what it really has, you can continue. Until then, leave Lithium batteries alone.

Comment: @BrunoVincent first rule of firefighting is NEVER use water on an electrical fire. Second rule is chemical fires are treated with extreme caution and knowledge of what will happen, water and burning lithium is a recipe for even more fire. [Lithium reacts violently with water](https://youtu.be/cTJh_bzI0QQ). You want either a CO2 or powder extinguisher.

Comment: @Mokubai - powder perhaps, CO2 on Li-ion, no. It breaks down CO2 to produce more oxygen… which is always the big problem with Li-ion, the fire produces oxygen anyway, which is why it can re-ignite. A bucket of water is actually a reasonably good way of putting them out, spraying isn't, until it's out. [Ships actually use mist sprays to keep them cool *after* a fire, not during.] Sand is good, but you'd need a bucketful you could dump from a distance. Technically, a battery fire isn't an 'electrical' fire. The battery is already in an explosive state, water isn't going to make that worse.

Comment: Oof hadn't thought about it liberating the cabon. Yeah. I think the main advice with those fires with their extreme reactions and heats is that the best thing you can do is to remove them to a clear open area and let them burn themselves out, almost anything you can add to mixed chemical fires might well just be another kind of fuel. I think most places dealing with battery fires just smother it in sand, hopefully the worst you'll get there is a ball of glass surrounding your fire.

Comment: @Mokubai - indeed. Looking at the linked video above, the chances of actually getting anywhere near it in the initial phase is going to be difficult in any case. In the video they do eventually get the fireman to drop it in water. The earlier tests look like they knew what was going to happen, demo for the video only. BTW, my initial comment was more in jest than anything serious as a 'solution'. I hadn't guessed we'd be off into more detail as to exactly how to go about this;)

Comment: Don’t do this, it will catch fire, it will be toxic. **Do Not Connect Them In Series**

Comment: “I don't mind if it makes the laptop bulkier and I'm willing to take out the bottom cover and cut it so it fits, I'm OK about duct tapping the whole thing, don't care what it looks like, I want battery lifespan!” Then buy a real battery with decent lifespan and recycle these things. You are only asking to creat a problem here.

Comment: This question should be left open, in my opinion, so that we can be sure to let people know the RIGHT thing to in such a situation. That the questions asks how to do something really wrong gives us opportunity to give correct advice.

Answer (score 5):

In series? **NO!!**

- That would feed your laptop with a voltage almost double that of it's rating!
- Would probably kill your laptop's circuitry for battery control and charging.
- Could also do damage to other devices plugged into it's motherboard.

Put out Li-ion fire with water? **good luck**

### First!

- Look up some videos on how violent the reactions are when people puncture or short circuit Li-Ion batteries (or packs).

### Next

- **Read up on voltages and capacity of batteries in series vs parallel**
- **Learn and initiate all necessary precautions regarding Li-Ion**

#### Then

- Now you could start thinking about if it's worth the hassle/risks.